# XML Parsing with same element tags but unique data

Tags: xml, parsing, grails, groovy, xmlslurper

I am parsing xml that has many of the same tag. Inside the tag there is a name of a value and then the value. My issue is is that I need to separate those values.

This is an example of the xml I have to parse

```
  <Event>
  <ipaddress>
  10.0.0.0.
  </ip>

  <sourcesystem>
  somwhere
  </sourcesystem>
  <username>
   fred91
  </username>
   <user>
   <username>
  fred91
   </username>
   <account>
  fredsaccount
   </account>
   <id>
    f2234232
    </id>
   </user>
  ////BELOW IS THE PORTION OF THE XML THAT I AM HAVING ISSUES WITH NOTICE MULTPLE OF THE SAME ELEMENT TAG BUT THE name and values are unique/////
 <event-details>
   <name>Prairie Farms</name>
   <value>Summer Lane Happy Land USA</value>
 </event-details>  
 <event-details>
   <name>House on fire</name>
   <value>ashes</value>
 </event-details>
</Event>
```

notice that the name of the events change and are not related. If they were related it would be easier to parse. The name is the name of the event and is unique. The value is linked to that unique name. My problem is trying to figure out how to parse out the unique name from the generic element tag and then assign that name the corresponding value.  I was told to try to use a collection but I am not sure how to go about doing that. Right now I have it parsing out like this.

```
sql.query(myQuery, []) { ResultSet rs ->
            while (rs.next()) { 

                  def parsing = new XmlSlurper().parseText(auditDetails)

                        def audit = new Audit()

                        audit.ipAddress = parsing."ip-address".text()
                        audit.sourceSystem = parsing."source-system".text()
                        audit.username = parsing."username".text()



                        parsing."user".each{
                            audit.username = parsing."user"."username".text()
                            audit.account = parsing."user"."account".text()
                            audit.id= parsing."user"."id".text()
                        }


                            /*if (parsing."event-details"."name".text().equals("createdTime")){
                                audit.name = parsing."event-details"."name".text
                                audit.createdTime = parsing."event-details"."value".text()
                            }*/
                            audit.name = parsing."event-details".name?.text()
                            audit.value = parsing."event-details".value?.text()
                        audit.eventDetails = parsing."event-details".text()
```

With audit being my object and parsing being my xmlslurper. 
Right now this just gives me all the "name" elements into one string and all there corresponding (In order respectively) values in another string. 
Like this:

**Name: Prairie FarmHouse on fire**

**Value: Summer Lane Happy Land USAashes**

I ultimately need it like

**Prairie Farms: Summer Lane Happy Land USA**

**House On Fire: ashes**

I have about 10 different unique names that I know of so far (found by looking at what this query receives with them strung together)

What would I have to write to get it so it picks out the unique event names and links it with its value.

```
parsing.'event-details'.each{
   if (parsing."event-details"."name".text().equals("createdTime")){
    audit.name = parsing."event-details"."name".text
    audit.createdTime = parsing."event-details"."value".text()
   }
}
```

^ This was my first thought, going with all the known unique names and going through and assigning a name to a value that way. This would of just linked createdTime with the value and ignore the rest as a test but it didn't even get that far.

Any suggestions or opinions?

Sorry if this is confusing. I find it kind of hard to explain

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using XmlSlurper, try:

```
def audit = parsing.'event-details'.iterator().collectEntries {
  [ it.name, it.value ]
}
```

#### Edit:

Ok, given the xml:

```
def x = '''<Event>
          |  <ipaddress>10.0.0.0</ipaddress>
          |  <sourcesystem>somwhere</sourcesystem>
          |  <username>fred91</username>
          |  <user>
          |    <username>fred91</username>
          |    <account>fredsaccount</account>
          |    <id>f2234232</id>
          |  </user>
          |  <event-details>
          |    <name>Prairie Farms</name>
          |    <value>Summer Lane Happy Land USA</value>
          |  </event-details>  
          |  <event-details>
          |    <name>House on fire</name>
          |    <value>ashes</value>
          |  </event-details>
          |</Event>'''.stripMargin()
```

And the Audit class:

```
@groovy.transform.ToString(includeNames=true)
class Audit {
  String ipAddress, sourceSystem, username, account, id
  Map eventDetails
}
```

You can do:

```
def audit = new XmlSlurper().parseText( x ).with { xml ->
  new Audit( ipAddress    : xml.ipaddress,
             sourceSystem : xml.sourcesystem,
             username     : xml.username,
             account      : xml.user.account,
             id           : xml.user.id,
             eventDetails : xml.'event-details'.iterator().collectEntries { [ it.name, it.value ] } )
}

println audit
```

to print:

```
Audit(ipAddress:10.0.0.0, sourceSystem:somwhere, username:fred91, account:fredsaccount, id:f2234232, eventDetails:[Prairie Farms:Summer Lane Happy Land USA, House on fire:ashes])
```

#### Note:

If you are using Groovy < 1.8.7, then change

```
             eventDetails : xml.'event-details'.iterator().collectEntries { [ it.name, it.value ] } )
```

to

```
             eventDetails : xml.'event-details'.inject( [:] ) { m, e -> m << [ (e.name): e.value ] } )
```

Comment: My bad for edit. 2 element list of `K, V` acceptable. I have so much to learn from you Tim. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro haha, no worries ;-) I learnt that off someone here I think!

Comment: Tim, Thanks for your responds and sorry it took awhile for me to get back to you. Right now I have audit = new Audit(). Audit has a lot more elements then just these event details and they parse out fine since they are not nested like the event-details. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern not sure what you mean...  Could you edit the question so it is more like the problem you've got?

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern Could you make the XML representative of the problem?  This now seems to be a completely different question to before (but I guess it is the same one, I just did not grasp the full picture)

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern can there be multiple `<user>` blocks? I ask as you have `parsing."user".each`

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern assuming there can be, I've updated my answer

Comment: there is only 1 user segment per xml portion.

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern and is `Event.username` always the same as `Event.user.username`?

Comment: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren$2.collectEntries() is applicable
I get this error on  eventDetails:xml.'event-details'.iterator().collectEntries{[it.name, itvale]}

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern what version of Groovy are you using?

Comment: Grails 2.1.0, groovy compiler 1.8

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern added a note at the bottom of my answer for if you are on groovy less than 1.8.7. It uses `inject` rather than `collectEntries`

Comment: YOU SIR ARE A MIRACLE WORKER!

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern glad to help!  Have fun :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unique keys would help you use `map` as below:

```
def audit = [:]
parsing.'event-details'.each{
      def name = parsing.event-details.name?.text() 
      def value = parsing.event-details.value?.text()

      //To make it easy to understand
      audit << [name: value]

      //I would have used
      audit << [(parsing.event-details.name?.text()): parsing.event-details.value?.text()]
}
```